# JSON array list parsing and displaying in tablayout

Tags: java, android, json

```
[  
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571807151270001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"8639062942",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"10.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019  6:07PM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768240",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768240",
      "namesList":"mohan",
      "seatNumbersList":"R10"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571753226370001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"8639062942",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"20.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019  5:53PM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768239",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768239",
      "namesList":"mohan,anu",
      "seatNumbersList":"R2,R1"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571751518700001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"9908288955",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"20.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019  5:51PM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768238",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768238",
      "namesList":"mohan,anurag",
      "seatNumbersList":"R6,R8"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571213557770001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"9908288955",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"700.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019 12:13PM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768214",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768214",
      "namesList":"mohan",
      "seatNumbersList":"R2"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571156507900001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"9908288955",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"800.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019 11:56AM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768211",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768211",
      "namesList":"thanks",
      "seatNumbersList":"6"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571153385700001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"8639062942",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"2400.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019 11:53AM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768210",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768210",
      "namesList":"mmmm,gxbndd",
      "seatNumbersList":"2,1"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571136385970001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"8639062942",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"1600.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019 11:36AM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768208",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768208",
      "namesList":"mohan,mohan",
      "seatNumbersList":"11,12"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571049465600001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"9908288955",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"2000.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019 10:49AM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768205",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768205",
      "namesList":"gshs,gshhsh",
      "seatNumbersList":"6,10"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190571034307000001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"8566655625",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"1000.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019 10:34AM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768203",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768203",
      "namesList":"fgh",
      "seatNumbersList":"2"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190570939356770001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"9699270484",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"30.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 26 2019  9:39AM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768202",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768202",
      "namesList":"mohan,anurag,hjjjj",
      "seatNumbersList":"R2,R1,R4"
   },
   {  
      "FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID":"20190561800266700001",
      "FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID":"6124",
      "CT_MOBILE_NUMBER":"9908288955",
      "FK_CT_ENTITY_ID":"81",
      "CT_AMOUNT":"10.00",
      "CT_DT_PROCESSED":"Feb 25 2019  6:00PM",
      "FK_CT_STATUS":"ABRS3768201",
      "CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE":"",
      "CT_STATUS_CODE":"success",
      "CT_ORDER_ID":"ABRS3768201",
      "namesList":"yh",
      "seatNumbersList":"R5"
   }
]
```

Above is my json array data, 
I want show this data in three different tabs those are

1. Completed
2. Reversed
3. Cancelled

depending upon CT_STATUS_CODE.

For example: if my CT_STATUS_CODE: success, I want to display that entire array list which are having same status code to be in Completed tab, similarly Reversed, cancelled also

Comment: Fetch data from the activity and send data to the fragments.

Comment: what exactly have you tried? and where are you stuck?

Comment: actually iam showing entire data in a recycler view along with card view adapter, but the requirement is implement tab layout for this entire data.@bhanukaushik

Comment: Please do not edit the content out of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

for this you have to create model class as below.

```
public class Data {

private String FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID, FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID, CT_MOBILE_NUMBER, FK_CT_ENTITY_ID, CT_AMOUNT, CT_DT_PROCESSED,
        FK_CT_STATUS, CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE, CT_STATUS_CODE, CT_ORDER_ID, namesList, seatNumbersList;

public Data(String FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID, String FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID, String CT_MOBILE_NUMBER, String FK_CT_ENTITY_ID,
            String CT_AMOUNT, String CT_DT_PROCESSED, String FK_CT_STATUS, String CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE, String CT_STATUS_CODE,
            String CT_ORDER_ID, String namesList, String seatNumbersList) {
    this.FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID = FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID;
    this.FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID = FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID;
    this.CT_MOBILE_NUMBER = CT_MOBILE_NUMBER;
    this.FK_CT_ENTITY_ID = FK_CT_ENTITY_ID;
    this.CT_AMOUNT = CT_AMOUNT;
    this.CT_DT_PROCESSED = CT_DT_PROCESSED;
    this.FK_CT_STATUS = FK_CT_STATUS;
    this.CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE = CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE;
    this.CT_STATUS_CODE = CT_STATUS_CODE;
    this.CT_ORDER_ID = CT_ORDER_ID;
    this.namesList = namesList;
    this.seatNumbersList = seatNumbersList;
}

public String getFK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID() {
    return FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID;
}

public void setFK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID(String FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID) {
    this.FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID = FK_CT_TRXN_UNIQUE_ID;
}

public String getFK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID() {
    return FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID;
}

public void setFK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID(String FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID) {
    this.FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID = FK_CT_LEDGERACCOUNT_ID;
}

public String getCT_MOBILE_NUMBER() {
    return CT_MOBILE_NUMBER;
}

public void setCT_MOBILE_NUMBER(String CT_MOBILE_NUMBER) {
    this.CT_MOBILE_NUMBER = CT_MOBILE_NUMBER;
}

public String getFK_CT_ENTITY_ID() {
    return FK_CT_ENTITY_ID;
}

public void setFK_CT_ENTITY_ID(String FK_CT_ENTITY_ID) {
    this.FK_CT_ENTITY_ID = FK_CT_ENTITY_ID;
}

public String getCT_AMOUNT() {
    return CT_AMOUNT;
}

public void setCT_AMOUNT(String CT_AMOUNT) {
    this.CT_AMOUNT = CT_AMOUNT;
}

public String getCT_DT_PROCESSED() {
    return CT_DT_PROCESSED;
}

public void setCT_DT_PROCESSED(String CT_DT_PROCESSED) {
    this.CT_DT_PROCESSED = CT_DT_PROCESSED;
}

public String getFK_CT_STATUS() {
    return FK_CT_STATUS;
}

public void setFK_CT_STATUS(String FK_CT_STATUS) {
    this.FK_CT_STATUS = FK_CT_STATUS;
}

public String getCT_VENDOR_RESPONSE() {
    return CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE;
}

public void setCT_VENDOR_RESPONSE(String CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE) {
    this.CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE = CT_VENDOR_RESPONSE;
}

public String getCT_STATUS_CODE() {
    return CT_STATUS_CODE;
}

public void setCT_STATUS_CODE(String CT_STATUS_CODE) {
    this.CT_STATUS_CODE = CT_STATUS_CODE;
}

public String getCT_ORDER_ID() {
    return CT_ORDER_ID;
}

public void setCT_ORDER_ID(String CT_ORDER_ID) {
    this.CT_ORDER_ID = CT_ORDER_ID;
}

public String getNamesList() {
    return namesList;
}

public void setNamesList(String namesList) {
    this.namesList = namesList;
}

public String getSeatNumbersList() {
    return seatNumbersList;
}

public void setSeatNumbersList(String seatNumbersList) {
    this.seatNumbersList = seatNumbersList;
}
 }
```

Now you have to create 3 different ArrayList as per your status in MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<Data> completedTask =new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Data> reversedTask =new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Data> cancelledTask =new ArrayList<>();
```

When you parse this JSON, use this condition

```
if (CT_STATUS_CODE.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
   // add data to
   ArrayList<Data> completedTask = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  if (CT_STATUS_CODE.equalsIgnoreCase("cancelled")) {
     // add data to
     ArrayList<Data> cancelledTask = new ArrayList<>();
    }
  if (CT_STATUS_CODE.equalsIgnoreCase("reversed")) {
     // add data to
     ArrayList<Data> reversedTask = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Now pass respective arrylist to respective fragment and set data to listview.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Get your json data as list of object by jsonconverter and then
you have to filter your list in your tab and then pass filtered list to respective tab's adapter to display.

you can filter list using below code.

```
        ArrayList<YourObject> filteredList =  list.stream().filter(new Predicate<YourObject>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(YourObject yourObject) {
                //user success and other keyword you are using in each respective tab
                return yourObject.ct_Status_code.contains("success");
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```